# Vue JS - Looping through components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, components, vue-component

I'm currently refactoring my code to make it look cleaner and I stumbled upon a section which doesn't really seem neat and may not be the best practise to execute this type of code.

Statistics.vue - In here I'm using a StatisticsCard component 3 times in order to display each of the relevant data for each component

```
<template>
  <div class="statistics-section">
    <img class="statistics-image" src="@/assets/img/images/img_stats@2x.png" alt="">
    <h3 class="section-title">Statistieken</h3>
    <p class="section-description">De studenten van Het Creiler hebben samen ...</p>
    <div class="statistics-cards">
      <StatisticsCard :imageUrl="require('@/assets/img/images/img_stats_km@2x.png')"
                      :title="'kilometers'"
                      :number="kilometers"
                      :type="'GELOPEN'"/>

      <StatisticsCard :imageUrl="require('@/assets/img/images/img_stats_collected@2x.png')"
                      :title="'stukken'"
                      :number="trashCollected"
                      :type="'AFVAL OPGRUIMD'"/>

      <StatisticsCard :imageUrl="require('@/assets/img/images/img_stats_photos@2x.png')"
                      :title="'foto\'s'"
                      :number="photosTaken"
                      :type="'GEDEELD'"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import StatisticsCard from '@/components/partials/onepager/StatisticsCard';

  export default {
    name: 'Statisticts',
    components: {StatisticsCard},
    props: {
      kilometers: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      trashCollected: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      photosTaken: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
    },
  }
```

School.vue - This is the main component and here I make all the relevant api calls. Statistics.vue is rendered to show all the information from the api.

```
<div class="section-grid">
    <Statistics :kilometers="schoolOnepager.statistics.collectedTrashCount"
                :trash-collected="schoolOnepager.statistics.schoolSharedPhotosTrashCount"
                :photos-taken="schoolOnepager.statistics.schoolTotalDistanceWalked"/>
</div>

...

computed: {
    schoolOnepager: function () {
      return this.$store.getters.getSchoolOnepager;
    },
}
```

Is there any better way I can do this instead of defining the statistics card component 3 times, can I perhaps loop through and let each one of them show the specific information.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array of statistics objects, and loop them.

for example in VueX Store:

```
statistics: [
 {
   title: 'kilometers',
   number: 12,
   type: 'GELOPEN'
 },
 {
   title: 'kilometers',
   number: 5,
   type: 'GELOPEN'
 }
]
```

*The data is requested from School.vue and from here the data in the store is mutated. In Statistics.vue the data is a computed property called schoolOnepager that import the statistics data from the VueX store

and then refactor your template components:

```
<StatisticsCard v-for="(statistic, i) in statistics" key="i" :imageUrl="require('@/assets/img/images/img_stats_km@2x.png')"
                  :title="statistic.title"
                  :number="statistic.number"
                  :type="statistic.type"/>
```

Comment: My concern about this is that how will I be able to specify which data is visible to the card from the api call?

Comment: Okay, interesting question. Do mean like in some cases you would only want to display 2 out of three statistics?

Comment: Not exactly. As I'm making an api call, the number in statisticsCard, will be different for every card, and will have to match the relevant data from the api. I then render Statistics.vue in a different component where I make the api call.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. In that case you would change: number: 'kilometers', to number: 12334, for example. the number would be coming from the api call you make.

Comment: Yes, that's right. In fact, if you have a look at my question 'School.vue' is where I make the api call, and for instance, to retrieve the kilometers i would do: "schoolOnepager.statistics.schoolTotalDistanceWalked"

Comment: Okay, let me just edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use v-for on a custom component, like any normal element:

```
<StatisticsCard v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"
 :title="'kilometers'"
 :number="item.kilometers"
 :type="item.type"
></StatisticsCard>
```

provided your items array should be like

```
[
 {
   title: 'kilometers',
   type: 'stunk'
},
{
   title: 'hgdfb',
   type: 'dvnvffv'
},
......
]
```

Comment: As you iterate you are sending the attr of that particular object as props

Comment: In that way each card will get it's specific information